# Using pluto.jl remotely

Tags: julia, jupyter, pluto.jl

I have recently started using Pluto.jl, and it is quite nice (and visually appealing). The question is: how do I set up a "pluto server", like the similar thing with `jupyter`. It must be easy, but I see no docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your ip address is 0.0.0.0 on port 1234 run:

```
Pluto.run("0.0.0.0", 1234)
```

Source: https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl/issues/398#issuecomment-689659028

Comment: The final comment in the thread is not encouraging, but thank you!

Comment: The new syntax is Pluto.run(host="0.0.0.0")
If you want to switch off the secret use Pluto.run(host="0.0.0.0", require_secret_for_access=false, launch_browser=false)